# Push onto array argument in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I have the following function:

```
function where(arr, num) {
  return arr.push(num);
}

where([40, 60], 50); // returns 3
```

I was expecting it to return [40,60,50] but it returns 3.

Thanks for you help.

Comment: Why would you want to do that anyway?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) states that `Array.prototype.push()` returns the length of the array. So you just need to push the new number and then return the array.

```
function where(arr, num) {
  arr.push(num);
  return arr;
}

myArray = where([40, 60], 50); // myArray === [40, 60, 50]
```

Comment: There is also no need to return the array

Comment: In your example, any modification will also be applied to an array passed to the function. `myArray = where(someArr,50).push(50)` `someArr` would also have 50 pushed to it twice.